# Azure Stream Analytics - output an event only when it is different to the previous one

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

i have a special situation that stream anlytics does not send an output event when using LAG in combination with input data in an array (json).

That is the input data from an datalogger:

20.04.2019 16:05:04> Device: [WISE-4012_00D0C9E43D10], Data:[{"PE":  1,"UID":"WISE-4012_00D0C9E43D10","TIM":"2019-04-20T16:04:55+01:00","Record":[[0, 0, 1,  0],[0, 1, 1,  0],[0, 2, 1,  0],[0, 3, 1,  0]]}]

I am using this query in azure stream analytics:

```
SELECT
    PE, UID, TIM,
    UDF.DI1(InputIoThub) As DI1
FROM
    [IoTHub]
WHERE
    LAG(DI1, 1) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) <> DI1
```

according tho this instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns

It looks like LAG can not deal with the UDF.

I replaced the UDF with following:

```
SELECT
   PE, UID, TIM,
   GetArrayElement(GetArrayElement(Record,0), 3) AS DI_1
INTO
   [toPowerBI]
FROM
   [IoTHub]
WHERE
   LAG(DI_1, 1) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) <> DI_1
```

but it does not work too.

Without the WHERE clouse, the stream generates an correct output, so I tried to use HAVING instead without success.

thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my question was not confusing, I was searching for a solution to send the digital input (DI_1) from an datalogger only when the value has changed. Reason therefore is to calculate a time difference in PowerBI.

In the meantime I found a solution:

The LAG function works fine, also with the WHERE

```
SELECT
   PE, UID, TIM,
   GetArrayElement(GetArrayElement(Record,0), 3) AS DI_1
INTO
   [toPowerBI]
FROM
   [IoTHub]
WHERE
   LAG(GetArrayElement(GetArrayElement(Record,0), 3), 1) 
   OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 10)) <>    
   GetArrayElement(GetArrayElement(Record,0), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls take a look at the query pattern for 'Determine if a value has changed'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns

Thanks

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!

The query pattern you mentioned describes exactly what I am searching for:

"Use LAG to peek into the input stream one event back and get the Make value. Then compare it to the Make value on the current event and output the event if they are different."

SELECT
    Make,
    Time
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP BY Time
WHERE
    LAG(Make, 1) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) <> Make

I understand that "Make" and "Time" are the two input columns. But why use function TIMESTAMP BY? 
In my query the function "LAG" and "DURATION" is marked red.

Comment: Timestamp by is used to process the events based on the timestamp in the event payload (application time) instead of processing it based on the time the events were received at the input source (event hub for example)

Comment: I found out, that LAG does not work in combination with the javascript UDF function. does anyone have an idea why?