# Output last X seconds of data every time a new event is consumed or every second from a streaming analytics job

Tags: azure, streaming, analytics

I have an Azure Streaming Analytics job that has an event hub as an input and a function as an output. With the stream of data, what I'm looking to do is to output the last X seconds of data every X seconds so that when the function in the output gets called, it is passed the last X seconds of data. Is there a way to achieve this with Streaming Analytics, or is there a better tool for this. I see there is a LAG function but I can't see how it can be used for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Stream Analytics - output an event only when it is different to the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693174/azure-stream-analytics-output-an-event-only-when-it-is-different-to-the-previo)

Comment: You can refer to [Common query patterns in Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns), [LAG (Azure Stream Analytics)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/lag-azure-stream-analytics) and [Compare previous and current message in Stream Analytics](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2019/02/03/compare-previous-and-current-message-in-stream-analytics/)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what I'm looking to do. I'm looking to take data as it is coming in and output 10 seconds of data in a rolling window where the output is the actual 10 seconds of data rather than an aggregate.